# Guardar array de input laravel 7

Tags: php, html, laravel

Tengo un formulario con varios parámetros de ingreso del usuario, pero el teléfono es dinámico si el usuario desea ingresar 5 ingresa 5 teléfonos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando deseo recibir en mi controlador solo me recibe el ultimo teléfono registrado por el usuario:

```
$telefonos=$request->telefono;
foreach($telefonos as $telefono) 
{
    $phone->telefono = $telefono;
    $phone->save();
}


<input id="telefono" type="text" class="form-control @error('telefono') is-invalid @enderror" name="telefono[]" value="{{ old('telefono') }}" required autocomplete="telefono" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías mostrar cómo está hecha la Base de datos y las relaciones para poder ayudarte mejor.

Tené en cuenta que si un usuario tiene muchos teléfonos la mejor forma de hacerlo es con una relación 1 a muchos. Esto requiere que crees una segunda tabla con clave foránea y relación con la de tus usuarios.

Una vez hecho todo eso, lo que tenés que hacer es una creación. Vos estás actualizando el mismo teléfono y guardando siempre en el mismo campo. Deberías sustituir eso por algo como:

```
$user = User::create(...);
$telefonos = $request->telefono;
foreach ($telefonos as $telefono)
{
    UserTelefonos::create([
        'user_id' = $user->id,
        'telefono' = $telefono
    ]);
}
```